# In undestanding and investigating regression coefficients, what's the difference between the F test vs the T-test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics

suppose I do a basic linear regression and output my summary statistics.  One of the metrics that I would get is the p-value, which is derived from the t-statistics and tests the null hypothesis that the slope is equal to 0.

If I do an anova on the model, I would get the sum of squares metrics, along with an F value.  I understand that the F statistic tests the overall model by testing the null B1 = B2 = B3  = 0. However, there is also an individual P_value for the F statistic for each coefficient.

What is the different between the p_value for the F statistic vs the p_value for the T statistic?

Answer (score 0):

The t-test and F-test are looking for evidence of different things. The F-test is measuring the variance between groups, while the t-test is measuring the difference in means between two groups.

In other words, the F-test will give evidence (low p-value) that the groups don't come from the same distribution if their sample variances are significantly different. The t-test gives evidence (low p-value) that the groups don't come from the same distribution if the differences in group means are significantly different.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks.  appreciate.  so I have definitly read those definitions before of the T-test and F test. So how does that relate to linear regression?

The null hypothesis for both t test and F test is beta = 0, so I'm not sure how that is related to variance between groups and variance in means.

Comment: For the t-test, the difference your are measuring is the difference between your calculated slope value (beta) and 0 (or whatever your null hypothesized value of beta is), and the SE is the standard error of the slope estimate. The F-test is testing that at least one of the betas is not equal to zero; essentially meaning the model does better than making predictions off a constant (aka just the intercept of the model).